# ngSwitch not changing to expression condition

Tags: angular

hey guys I have a ngSwitch that isn’t working. It appears that the conditions are not being registered completely? it is always at the default div. I am trying to update a picture and based on the status show the correct element (noPicture[default], imgLoading, imgReady[show the picture)here is the html

```html
            <ng-container [ngSwitch]="'imgStatus'">
              <div *ngSwitchCase="'imgLoading'">LOADING</div>
              <img *ngSwitchCase="'imgReady'" [src]="profileURL" class="ion-align-self-center" />
              <app-default-profile-picture
                *ngSwitchDefault
                [lastNames]="lastNames"
                [contactBox]="true"
              ></app-default-profile-picture>
            </ng-container>
```

*note** I have tried with and without the quotes but based on [this article](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngif-and-ngswitch/) it looks like I need the quotes because the condition is a quote
here is the function:

```js
  private takePicture(source: number): void {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      // ...
    };

   this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData: string): void => {
        this.imgStatus = 'imgLoading'; // here I set it as loading

        this.api.uploadImage(imagePayload).subscribe((response: ImageResponse): any => {
          if(response.code === 200) {
            this.extPicture = response.data;
            this.imgStatus = 'imgReady';
          } else {
            this.imgStatus = 'imgError';
          }
        })
```

nothing changes, anyone can see what I’m missing here? thanks

Comment: use this [ngSwitch]="imgStatus"

Comment: AHHHHHGHSDFGHDFHSGHSDFGHSDFHGHSDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way `<ng-container [ngSwitch]="imgStatus">`